# Using anonymous functions in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, dynamic, anonymous-function

I want to program to solve a linear program using dynamic programming.

Lets say I have 3 variables in my objective function. Then I want to consider each variable at a time and find the optimal value by using `fminsearch` or something.

Now my code has three different anonymous functions that solves each variable. I want to do this in a loop so that it is efficient. How can I use anonymous function in a loop?

```
Func1 = @(x) 2*x(1) 
Func2 = @(y) 3*y(1)
Func3 = @(z) 4*z(1)
```

I want to do something like:

```
Func(i) = @(x(i)) k(i)*x(i)
```

---

**Example:**

```
max z = 3x1+5x2
s.t.
x1 <=4
2x2  <=12
3x1 + 2x2  <=18 
x1>=0
x2>=0
```

What I tried so far:

```
func1 = @(x) -3*x(1);
[x1,minZ] = fmincon(func1,x0,A,b,[],[],lb,ub,[],options)
func2 = @(x) -5*x(1)-3*x1; %substituting from previous solution for x1...
[x2,minZ] = fmincon(func2,x0,A2,b2,[],[],lb2,ub2,[],options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x0 = 0;

fun_b2 = @(x) 18 - (3 * x);
fun_fm = '@(x)(-5*{x2})-(3*{x1})';
opts = optimset('Algorithm','active-set','TolFun',1e-6);

% 1st parameter of the row: A as column vector
% 2nd parameter of the row: B first value (the second one is evaluated into the for loop
% 3rd parameter of the row: a column vector containing the upper and lower bounds
params = {
    [1 3] 4 [0 Inf];
    [2 2] 12 [0 3]
};
params_size = size(params,1);

res = NaN(params_size,1);

for i = 1:params_size
    % take the function in string form and replace the current parameter placeholder with x(i)
    fun = fun_fm;
    fun = strrep(fun,['{x' num2str(i) '}'],'x(1)');

    % replace the previous parameter placeholders with the known values
    for j = 1:i
        fun = strrep(fun,['{x' num2str(j) '}'],num2str(res(j)));
    end

    % replace the next parameter placeholders with 0
    if (i < params_size)
        for j = (i+1):params_size
            fun = strrep(fun,['{x' num2str(j) '}'],'0');
        end
    end

    % transform the string into a function handle
    fun = str2func(fun);

    % transpose the first parameter (A) to row vector
    A = params{i,1}.';

    % take the first B value and calculate the second one with the function
    b1 = params{i,2};
    b2 = fun_b2(x1);

    bounds = params{i,3};

    [xi,min_z] = fmincon(fun,x0,A,[b1 b2],[],[],bounds(1),bounds(2),[],opts);

    res(i) = xi;
end
```

Comment: This doesn't allow me to solve three times. I have to solve for x y and z on three different steps.

Comment: Ok can you edit providing the full algorithm please, this is pretty unclear.

Comment: % max z = 3x1+5x2
% s.t.
% x1         <=4
%       2x2  <=12
% 3x1 + 2x2  <=18 
% x1>=0
% x2>=0

func1 = @(x) -3*x(1);
x0=0;
A = [1;3];
b = [4 18];
lb = [0];
ub = [inf];
options = optimset('Algorithm','active-set','TolFun', 1e-6 );
[x1,minZ] = fmincon(func1,x0,A,b,[],[],lb,ub,[],options)


func2 = @(x) -5*x(1)-3*x1; %substituting from previous solution for x1...
% and solving for x2 variable
x0=0;
A2 = [2;2];
b2 = [12 ;18-3*x1];
lb2 = [0];
ub2 = [3];
[x2,minZ] = fmincon(func2,x0,A2,b2,[],[],lb2,ub2,[],options)

Comment: Not so clear but know I understand what you're looking for... wait I edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution and it works. Tell me if you need your function to be much more dynamic because it may take long to elaborate.